# How to take input in python

Tags: python-3.7

Input format
1.The first line contains T,the number of test cases
2. The following T lines contains a number n
Example:
5
1
7
10
300
55
I am new to this language i Know the simple inputs but I couldn't understand this multiple input pattern

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.